# Magento2: How to move VAT field in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms, vat

I need to move the VAT field to top, I can not find the file with the form or the file where I can modify it

Comment: can you post the snapshot of the page.

Answer (score 4):

To change the sort order of fields on Checkout you need a LayoutProcessorPlugin.

```
'namespace/module/etc/frontend/di.xml'

...
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="checkout-sort-order-plugin" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
...
```

Now, lets create the plugin.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'label' => __('VAT number'),
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        ],
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.vat_id',
        'sortOrder' => 1,
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

You can change the `'sortOrder' => 1,` to place it between any two fields you want, but now, with value 1 is placed before all fields Checkout.