# How to move VAT field in billing Address in checkout Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

There is an answer here : [How to move VAT field in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163785/magento2-how-to-move-vat-field-in-checkout)

This does not explain how to move it also for the billing address. I imagine it's possible to combine these moves in the same file but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to add the custom module to move the vat from first with the link that you attached.
And in the afterProcess() function, add the codes with this.

```
$whereBilling = $this->_helper->getConfig('checkout/options/display_billing_address_on');

        if ($whereBilling == 0) {
            //$paymentsList = [ "checkmo-form", "cashondeliver-form", "purchaseorder-form", ];
            $paymentsList = $this->getActivePaymentMethods();
            
            foreach ($paymentsList as $payment_code => $model) {
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymment_name]['children']['street']['vat_id']['sortOrder'] = 20;
}
} else {
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['vat_id']['sortOrder'] = 20;
}
```